# How do I pass an attribute to a function in the same class?

Tags: python-3.x, class

I am having trouble with this code. The goal is to "encrypt" a message that the user inputs by reversing the input. The lesson was originally written as a functional block of code, but I wanted to convert it to object-oriented programming and now I get an error. Please let me know if I have any other issues in this code.

This is the code

```
class Encrypt:
    def __init__(self,message,translated): 
        self.message = message # user input
        self.translated = translated # encrypted result

    def encryptionProcess(self,message): # encrypting functino 
        i = len(message) - 1
        while i >= 0:
            self.translated = self.translated + self.message[i]
            i = i - 1

m1 = Encrypt(input(),'') # setting the class attributes
m1.encryptionProcess(message) # calling the function
print(Encrypt.translated) # printing the result
```

This is the error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "oopEncrypt.py", line 13, in <module>
    m1.encryptionProcess(message)
NameError: name 'message' is not defined
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Accessing class instance attributes is done with the `self` parameter, passed as the first parameter to the class instance method.

Try this:

```
class Encrypt:

    def __init__(self, message):
        self.message = message  # user input

    def encryptionProcess(self):  # encrypting functin
        translated = "".join(reversed(self.message))
        return translated

m1 = Encrypt(input("Enter word to encrypt > "))
translated = m1.encryptionProcess()
print("Encrypted Word:", translated)
```

`self` is the instance of the current class.

You may find the python 3 class docs a useful reference: https://docs.python.org/3.6/tutorial/classes.html